# Looking for advice on how to set up parameters for CNN (sequential)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, model, conv-neural-network

Is there any guide I can follow to help set up a CNN, using a sequential method? I have a dataset of over 100,000 images from Kaggle and am looking to categorize them into 25 different groups.

I understand I need to add Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, and Dense layers. But I'm unsure of how many to put and what parameters to set them at. I understand that I will have to do trial and error until I get the accuracy high but right now I am getting an accuracy of 0%. I found the following code snippet online which works for a 10 category classification and I'm trying to see how this would be changed to go to 25 groups.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 1))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

I just want advice on any resources or tips on setting it up!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this architecture with few changes.since you have 25 categories your output layer should have 25 units.

```
model.add(Dense(25, activation='softmax'))
```

your input shape should match to the training image sizes.So you need to change this line according to your dataset.

```
input_shape=(200, 200, 1)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, I did try this, however it gave a 0% accuracy rate. I know the rest of the code works because I was able to recreate the original work found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/tutorial-using-deep-learning-and-cnns-to-make-a-hand-gesture-recognition-model-371770b63a51). I'll keep looking!